# PAR Packer Executable Size

Tags: windows, perl, par

I have been using PAR:Packer (pp) to create binaries for windows for a while. They have always been understandably large (around 6-8MB), recently I updated my packages (I use stawberry perl on windows) and now it is producing binaries that are almost 20MB! I understand it is including an entire perl environment with all needed modules, but it is getting out of hand, and a little embarrassing to hand someone a simple script that is 19MB! Is there anyway to reduce the binary size? Any one know why the size has increases in the last couple releases or PAR Packer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install new modules in your Perl environment (or even only upgrade some), *pp* will include a lot of additional files over time even if they are not used by your script. It's because *pp* is more safe than strict concerning what to include that it picks up a lot of useless dependencies.

The trick is to use *two* Perl environments. One for development and another one only for building binaries. For the building environment, start from a fresh Perl install, install PAR::Packer and *only* the modules needed by your application.

With my building environment, I can produce a Tk binary of only 5 Mb. With my development environment (which has a lot of junk from CPAN) on the same machine, the same script is 13 Mb.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>What difference does it make?</strike> IMHO, I wouldn't be concerned with *size*, only with *performance*

<strike>PAR doesn't hide anything from you, you want</strike>If you're curious to know which files get packed, if they're stripped of pod, etc etc, all you have to do is look inside `unzip -d foo foo.exe`

FWIW, AFAIK, the size hasn't changed, so you must be using lots and lots of modules.

- Typical no-module-print-print-pl yields about 1.6M

  Load Moose/Tk and you're at about 5.1M

  Load Gtk2/Glib/Pango/Cairo/threads and you're at about 9.7M

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, this is simply not accurate. A simple script including warnings and strict only easily surpasses 10MB. Also, there was an increase in size after upgrading all of my packages. running pp on my machine vs pp on another machine with an older PAR module with the same code produced a size difference of several MB, so something changed...